# How to forward logs to s3 from yarn container?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am setting up Spark on Hadoop Yarn cluster in AWS EC2 machines.
This cluster will be ephemeral (For few hours within a day) and hence i want to forward the container logs generated to s3.
I have seen Amazon EMR supporting this feature by forwarding logs to s3 every 5 minutes

Is there any built in configuration inside hadoop/spark that i can leverage ..?

Any other solution to solve this issue will also be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for YARN log aggregation.

Haven't tried changing it myself, but you can configure `yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir` to point to S3 filesystem, assuming you've setup your core-site.xml accordingly

`yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds` + 
`yarn.log-aggregation.retain-check-interval-seconds`  will determine how often the YARN containers will ship out their logs

The alternate solution would be to build your own AMI that has Fluentd or Filebeat pointing at the local YARN log directories, then setup those log forwarders to write to a remote location. For example, Elasticsearch (or one of the AWS log solutions) would be a better choice than just S3

Comment: Hi can you point me to the documentation where they are using these config to forward logs to S3. I initially tried with these config but it didnt work. EMR is specially built for forwarding logs to S3.

Comment: There is no such documentation that I know of. As I said, in theory these are the only properties that YARN uses to control where log files go. EMR has no "special configs" that I know of either. However, you are welcome to install EMR yourself and go look at the config files. You could also look at other solutions like Qubole on AWS